# How can I check if some text exist or not in the page using Selenium?

Tags: validation, selenium, webdriver, assert

I'm using Selenium WebDriver, how can I check if some text exist or not in the page? Maybe someone recommend me useful resources where I can read about it. Thanks

Comment: In case anyone looking for same in Robot Framework - this may help -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242291/robotframework-how-to-check-text-on-page

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), it's not that hard. Simply search for all elements containing the given text:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]"));
Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", list.size() > 0);
```

The [official documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) is not very supportive with tasks like this, but it is the basic tool nonetheless.

The [JavaDocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html) are greater, but it takes some time to get through everything useful and unuseful.

To learn XPath, just [follow the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=xpath%20tutorial). The spec is also a surprisingly good read.

---

**EDIT:**

Or, if you don't want your [Implicit Wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits) to make the above code wait for the text to appear, you can do something in the way of this:

```
String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", bodyText.contains(text));
```

Comment: I get notification  - WebElement cannot be resolved to a type, Assert cannot be resolved to a type, List cannot be resolved to a type - I need add something ti import to resolve this?

Comment: Do you remember the shortcuts I told you yesterday? They help ;-). If you're working with Java, you should know where the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) lies. If you're working with the Selenium library, you should know where the [`WebElement`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) lies. And if you added `assert` tag to your question and use Java, you should know where [`Assert`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) lies (needs JUnit)...

Comment: sorry for such question, I'm new to selenium and java)

Comment: Getting the body text is not the right way to search for text on a page. Getting the body text will test if the string exists in the source code, but it doesn't really test that the string exists on a page. For example, there may be broken PHP script where a closing ?> is missing, meaning the test will pass, but the page will not be rendering correctly.

Comment: .size() not working for me in NodeJS. I ended up going with the .getPageSource() solution below.

Answer (score 25):

This will help you to check whether required text is there in webpage or not.

```
driver.getPageSource().contains("Text which you looking for");
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'getPageSource'`

Comment: @Cerin It looks like you're in Python? This post is likely in Java, so you might want to adapt it to `get_page_source`. (I haven't checked this one specifically, but mostly camelCase becomes snake_case.)

Answer (score 14):

You could retrieve the body text of the whole page like this:

```
bodyText = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
```

then use an assert to check it like this:

```
self.assertTrue("the text you want to check for" in bodyText)
```

Of course, you can be specific and retrieve a specific DOM element's text and then check that instead of retrieving the whole page.

Comment: If you're going to assert and check if an element is in something, I'd recommend `self.assertIn("the text you want to check for", bodyText)`

Answer (score 7):

There is no verifyTextPresent in Selenium 2 webdriver, so you've to check for the text within the page source. See some practical examples below.

#### Python

In Python driver you can write the following function:

```
def is_text_present(self, text):
    return str(text) in self.driver.page_source
```

then use it as:

```
try: self.is_text_present("Some text.")
except AssertionError as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
```

To use regular expression, try:

```
def is_regex_text_present(self, text = "(?i)Example|Lorem|ipsum"):
    self.assertRegex(self.driver.page_source, text)
    return True
```

See: [`FooTest.py` file](https://github.com/mycognitive/ads_tests/blob/master/selenium/FooTest.py) for full example.

Or check below few other alternatives:

```
self.assertRegexpMatches(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/label").text, r"^[\s\S]*Weather[\s\S]*$")
assert "Weather" in self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.classname1.classname2>div.clearfix>label").text
```

<sup>Source: [Another way to check (assert) if text exists using Selenium Python](http://www.emalis.com/2013/08/another-way-to-check-assert-if-text-exists-using-selenium-python/)</sup>

#### Java

In Java the following function:

```
public void verifyTextPresent(String value)
{
  driver.PageSource.Contains(value);
}
```

and the usage would be:

```
try
{
  Assert.IsTrue(verifyTextPresent("Selenium Wiki"));
  Console.WriteLine("Selenium Wiki test is present on the home page");
}
catch (Exception)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Selenium Wiki test is not present on the home page");
}
```

<sup>Source: [Using verifyTextPresent in Selenium 2 Webdriver](http://www.seleniumwiki.com/webdriver/using-verifytextpresent-in-selenium-2-webdriver/)</sup>

---

#### Behat

For Behat, you can use [Mink extension](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension). It has the following methods defined in [`MinkContext.php`](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/src/Behat/MinkExtension/Context/MinkContext.php):

```
/**
 * Checks, that page doesn't contain text matching specified pattern
 * Example: Then I should see text matching "Bruce Wayne, the vigilante"
 * Example: And I should not see "Bruce Wayne, the vigilante"
 *
 * @Then /^(?:|I )should not see text matching (?P<pattern>"(?:[^"]|\\")*")$/
 */
public function assertPageNotMatchesText($pattern)
{
    $this->assertSession()->pageTextNotMatches($this->fixStepArgument($pattern));
}

/**
 * Checks, that HTML response contains specified string
 * Example: Then the response should contain "Batman is the hero Gotham deserves."
 * Example: And the response should contain "Batman is the hero Gotham deserves."
 *
 * @Then /^the response should contain "(?P<text>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
 */
public function assertResponseContains($text)
{
    $this->assertSession()->responseContains($this->fixStepArgument($text));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In c# this code will help you to check whether required text is there in webpage or not.

```
Assert.IsTrue(driver.PageSource.Contains("Type your text here"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for text in your page source as follow:

```
Assert.IsTrue(driver.PageSource.Contains("Your Text Here"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, you can simply check as follow:

```
# on your `setUp` definition.
from selenium import webdriver
self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()

self.assertTrue('your text' in self.selenium.page_source)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python:**

```
driver.get(url)
content=driver.page_source
if content.find("text_to_search"): 
    print("text is present in the webpage")
```

Download the html page and use find()

Answer (score 0):

```
  boolean Error = driver.getPageSource().contains("Your username or password was incorrect.");
    if (Error == true)
    {
     System.out.print("Login unsuccessful");
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.print("Login successful");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JUnit+Webdriver

```
assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//this/is/the/xpath/location/where/the/text/sits".getText(),"insert the text you're expecting to see here");
```

If in the event your expected text doesn't match the xpath text, webdriver will tell you what the actual text was vs what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

string_website.py

search string in webpage

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get("https://www.python.org/")
    content=browser.page_source

    result = content.find('integrate systems')
    print ("Substring found at index:", result ) 

    if (result != -1): 
    print("Webpage OK")
    else: print("Webpage NOT OK")
    #print(content)
    browser.close()
```

**run**

`python test_website.py`

Substring found at index: 26722

Webpage OK

d:\tools>python test_website.py

Substring found at index: -1       ; -1 means nothing found

Webpage NOT OK

Answer (score 0):

You can check a source code if the text exists:

```
   source_code = driver.page_source
   if "Im not a Robot" not in source_code:
```