# How to verify a Text present in the loaded page through WebDriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, assertion

I need to verify a Text present in the page through WebDriver. I like to see the result as boolean (true or false). Can any one help on this by giving the WebDriver code?

Comment: In what programming language? What browser? Does the text always appear in the same element? Where? What element?

Answer (score 9):

As zmorris points `driver.getPageSource().contains("input");` is not the proper solution because it searches in all the html, not only the texts on it.
I suggest to check this question: [how can I check if some text exist or not in the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454798/how-can-i-check-if-some-text-exist-or-not-in-the-page)
and the recomended way explained by Slanec:

```
String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", bodyText.contains(text));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be:
    String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue(true, bodyText.contains(text));

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that which returns boolean. The following java code in WebDriver with TestNG or JUnit can do:

```
protected boolean isTextPresent(String text){
    try{
        boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains(text);
        return b;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Now call the above method as below:

```
assertTrue(isTextPresent("Your text"));
```

Or, there is another way. I think, this is the better way:

```
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
try {
                  assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*    Your text here\r\n\r\n[\\s\\S]*$"));
  } catch (Error e) {
     verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
   }
```

Comment: Your question seems to be lacking some information. 1) What language are you using? 2) Are you using any test framework as JUnit or TestNG?

Comment: Yes, I prefer the last one of above answer

Comment: This is a better solution as it can be leveraged for multiple text values

Comment: I don't think it will valid if the case is insensitive...

Answer (score 2):

Driver.getPageSource() is a bad way to verify text present. Suppose you say, `driver.getPageSource().contains("input");` That doesn't verify "input" is present on the screen, only that "input" is present in the html, like an input tag.

I usually verify text on an element by using xpath:

```
boolean textFound = false;  
try {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'someText')]"));
    textFound = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    textFound = false;
}
```

If you want an exact text match, just remove the contains function:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='someText']));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bothered about the location of the text present, then you could use Driver.PageSource property as below:

Driver.PageSource.Contains("expected message");

Comment: Is there any way of finding the text without page source and more over i need to print True if the text exists any where in the page and False if the text doen't...

Answer (score 0):

Note: Not in boolean

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");

if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Ur message"))
  {
    System.out.println("Pass");
  }
else
  {
    System.out.println("Fail");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Ruby programmers here is how you can assert.** 
    **Have to include Minitest to get the asserts**

```
    assert(@driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("Name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is most suitable way to verify a text on page. You can use any one out of 8 locators as per your convenience.

String Verifytext= driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().trim();
Assert.assertEquals(Verifytext, "Paste the text here which needs to be verified");

Answer (score 0):

If you want check only displayed objects(**C#**):

```
    public bool TextPresent(string text, int expectedNumberOfOccurrences)
    {
        var elements = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[text()[contains(.,'" + text + "')]]"));
        var dispayedElements = 0;
        foreach (var webElement in elements)
        {
            if (webElement.Displayed)
            {
                dispayedElements++;
            }
        }
        var allExpectedElementsDisplayed = dispayedElements == expectedNumberOfOccurrences;
        return allExpectedElementsDisplayed;
    }
```