# Can the PageSource property in Selenium be updated as JavaScript loads data?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to determine if there's specific text on the page. I'm doing this:

```
public static void WaitForPageToLoad(this IWebDriver driver, string textOnPage)
{
    var pageSource = driver.PageSource.ToLower();
    var timeOut = 0;

    while (timeOut < 60)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (pageSource.Contains(textOnPage.ToLower()))
        {
            timeOut = 60;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the web driver's `PageSource` property isn't updated after the initial load. The page I'm navigating to loads a bunch of data via JS after the page has already loaded. I don't control the site, so I'm trying to figure out a method to get the updated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve the wrong problem. You need to wait for the text to appear using an XPath locator:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver);
var xpath = $"//*[contains(., '{textOnPage}')]";

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(xpath));
```

Comment: That's not a valid XPath

Comment: @JeffC: Sorry about that. Missed the slashes at the beginning.

Comment: Ah. Right. I should've thought of that. Thanks for the help. That works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to search entire page?
I'll reference you to here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41223770/1387701

with this code:

```
String Verifytext= driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().trim();
```

You can then check to see if the Verifytext contains the string you're checking for.

This works MUCH better if you can narrow the location of the text down to a particular webElement other than the body.