# How it would be in selenium driver using python

Tags: python, selenium

I know if we want to discontinue the loop when some thing found in the page like

```
    if "page not found"  in browser.page_source:
        return
```

but how it would be if something not found in the page source then return...

for i.e. but this doesn't work

```
    if "next page"  not in browser.page_source:
        return
```

please how to fix it..

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? Does it always returns?

Comment: yes always return if next page is in the page source if want it to return when next page is not in the page source

Comment: Could you provide HTML?

Comment: it is very simple html <span>next page</span>

Comment: There are 2 possibilities: 1. `<span>next page</span>` is inside an iframe  2. `<span>next page</span>` is generated by JavaScript. You have to provide more HTML so I can figure out what is the problem.

Comment: <a class="page-link" href="/vsearch/p?openFacets=N%2CG%2CCC%2CI&amp;f_N=S&amp;f_G=de%3A5000&amp;f_I=4&amp;page_num=2" rel="next" title="Next Page" data-li-page="2">Next Next >;</a>

Comment: is there any solution

Comment: Can you print the page_source then manually check if the 'next page' exists or not? If not, you may need to get innerHTML of body instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your code in the try-except block

```
try:
return str("your text") in self.driver.page_source
except:
return false
```

Checkout this link - 
[how can I check if some text exist or not in the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454798/how-can-i-check-if-some-text-exist-or-not-in-the-page)

Comment: is there any solution