# Python Selenium Check for Word in Inspect

Tags: python, selenium

so i was planning to use a answer on this: [How can I check if some text exist or not in the page using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454798/how-can-i-check-if-some-text-exist-or-not-in-the-page-using-selenium)

but theyre all using the page_source of the site,, but on the page source my word isnt there, but on the inspect elements, so i was wondering if i could use that.

Comment: It should be present in the source if it is present in the inspect elements tab. Afterall, they are the same thing.

Comment: i was planning on using selenium with some discord stuff, but there the page_source isnt the inspect elems...

Comment: Maybe this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30179058/8878627

Comment: can you share HTML or page url ?

Comment: @SPSharan : I was using that

Comment: @cruisepandey : Example: [Discord](https://www.discord.com/authorize-ip#token=example)